# Series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} . \log(\frac{1}{n})$, is it converging or diverging?

Tags: real-analysis

> Check whether this series converge or diverge
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} . \log\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Would be nice if someone explained it. Thanks.

I have tried comparision to 1/n, but it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.What have you tried?

Comment: Comparison to $\sum(1/n)$.

Comment: I have tried comparision to 1/n, but it does not work.

Comment: Evidently, it *does* work, as in the answer from Yulia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log(n)} n \sim \int _{2}^\infty \frac{\log(n)} n dn$$ and
$$\int  \frac{\log(n)} n dn=\frac 12 \log^2(n)$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the question is actually log(1/n) not log(n)

Comment: @NateDogg. $\log(1/n)=-\log(n)$

Comment: But then what about the negative sign, wouldn't removing that change the expression?

Comment: @NateDogg. It just changes the sign.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(\frac{1}{n})}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-\log(n)}{n}.$$

Knowing that $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, and comparing the asymptotical behavior:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\dfrac{\frac{-\log(n)}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\log(n)=\infty$

it follows that $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n)}{n}$ also diverges. Namely to $-\infty$.

Or just simply noting that

$\dfrac{1}n\leq\ \dfrac{\log(n)}n$ for $n\geq3.$

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Working too hard, Yulia; you don't need asymptotics, you only need $|\log n|$ bounded away from zero for large $n$.