# Prove that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log{(k)}}{10k}$ diverges.

Tags: calculus

Using the comparison test, prove that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log{(k)}}{10k}$ diverges.
Basically this series behaves like $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10k} = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ which we know diverges (this can be proved by using the integral test). To make this formal we use the comparison test.

For any $k\geq 10$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\log{(k)}}{k} > \frac{1}{k}
\end{equation*}
But the series
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}
\end{equation*}
diverges, so by the comparison test $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log{(k)}}{10k}$ diverges too as required.
Is this good?

Comment: Yes, since the divergence does not care about finitely many terms in the sum (which is the first ten terms as you mentioned).

Comment: Great thanks out very much

Comment: It doesn't impact your argument but $\dfrac{\ln k}{k} > \dfrac1k$ for $k \geqslant 3$.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323836/series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-log-frac1n-is-it-converging-or-d/3323842#3323842